# Can MathJax be enabled on Stack Overflow for teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am not able to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). Can it somehow be enabled? I am using the 'Basic' version.

If it cannot be enabled right now, is it a planned feature of SO for Teams?

Comment: @weegee - the question you linked relates to public SO, which is for programming questions. My question relates to a "closed" version of SO for businesses, and as I understand it is targeted at diverse teams, not only software developers.

Comment: I don't see much (as in none) javascript  being loaded per channel and MathJAX is local browser thingy so I doubt that this is available overall let alone per team.

Comment: I recall I had seen a stand alone script for adding MathJax support when a site doesn't support it natively but I can't find it any more https://stackapps.com/questions

Comment: @rene won't the dependency slow the page? SO for teams will be affected a lot. Maybe that's why they never implemented it?

Comment: @weegee yes, that is why it isn't avaialble on SO proper. If paying customers agree with a slow repsonse due to MathJAX enabled on their team and their team alone I see no reason why you wouldn't see if you can make that fly.

Comment: @rene - Thanks for the reference (didn't know about stackapps before).

Comment: I have the same question. Maybe one could also use KaTeX (which is faster). So what steps do I need to do to enable mathjax or katex for my team site globally (just like in mathoverflow)?

Comment: I would also be interested in seeing if this is on the horizon. I think this would be a great feature for teams in an academic setting.

Answer (score 5):

Not ideal, but in the mean time while this isn't implemented, I found a [Userscript](https://gist.github.com/neighthan/756fbb4ce6ccc40b77cc4eeb13379fe4) that lets you load Mathjax on select sites. This is inconvenient because it requires each user to have this script, but for a small team this might be an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Here are some [Bookmarks for MathJax](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html). They were created & maintained by Math.SE mod [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn). These bookmarks are used extensively in the Math & Physics chatrooms to provide MathJax support. They aren't as convenient as a Userscript, but they work on mobile devices.

Comment: I just tested the `render MathJax` bookmark on a draft answer on this page, and it works correctly. So I *assume* it will work on Teams pages.

Comment: It does indeed work in teams. But I have not found a way to add that link - the link feature checks that the url is well formatted. I suspect on pc there's some trick to introduce it. Annoying.