# CircuitLab is not available in Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am subscribed to electronics.stackexchange and [CircuitLab](https://wiki.opensourceecology.org/wiki/CircuitLab) is very handy to embed schematics and simulation in your answers.

I have subscribed to 'Teams' in order to discuss schematics, but CircuitLab is not available (no icon to open the schematic). Maybe because 'Teams' is hosted by Stack Overflow? (however, it was advertised from within Stack Exchange...)

Is there a way to have CircuitLab available? Otherwise that 'Teams' seems a bit useless...

Comment: Tl;dr: because Teams is based off of SO, no.

Comment: Related question about MathJax: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390031/6083675